# GLContext cannot be resolved

Tags: java, opengl, syntax, lwjgl

Im working with lwjgl version 3.1.0 and GLContext doesnt seem to exist.

`import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;`

im getting an error with this line.

any ideas?

Comment: Does anything else from `org.lwjgl.opengl` "exist"?

Comment: @httpdigest I thought it because im using a raytracing test project that uses lwjgl 3 but it also had GLContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is correct. `org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext` *does not* exist in LWJGL 3.

Comment: oh okay sorry. Im pretty new with opengl